Does anyone know if the :bind feature of defhydra works?
The home page of the Emacs hydra package
https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra
indicates that there's a :bind key for the defhydra macro. However, it's undocumented how it works. The only statement about it is:

The :bind key provides a lambda to be used to bind each head. This is
quite advanced and rarely used, you're not likely to need it. But if
you would like to bind your heads with e.g. bind-key instead of
define-key you can use this option.
The :bind key can be overridden by each head. This is useful if you
want to have a few heads that are not bound outside the hydra.

There's no information given about what parameters the lambda takes, or how it's presented, nor are examples given there or anywhere else that I've seen.
Does anyone know if this feature works? If so, does anyone know how to use it?
